# Javascript dynamic onClick

Tags: javascript, codemirror, skulpt

I have 2 codemirror components on a page and when you click the "Run" button, I want it to run the code above the button only.

The issue I am having is it is only running the last codemirror component and does not run the individual code the way I like it to.

Is there any way in the button onClick function below to set that up dynamically?

Codemirror components with onClick buttons:

```
<div id="content">
        <section class="method first-of-group" id="intro">
          <div class="method-area method-area-expanded">
            <div class="method-copy">
              <h1 class="lesson-name">python title</h1>

            <div class="method-example">
              <div id="side-view">
                <div id="side-left">
                  <textarea id="yourcode" cols="40" rows="10">
my_name = "Sir Python"
print("Hello and welcome " + my_name + "!")
                    </textarea
                  >
                  <script type="text/javascript">
                    // insert codemirror
                    var myCodeMirror = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(yourcode, {
                      lineNumbers: true,
                      mode: "python"
                    });
                  </script>
                </div>
                <br />

                <div id="side-right">
                  <div id="console">
                    <pre id="output"></pre>
                  </div>
                  <!-- If you want turtle graphics include a canvas -->
                  <div id="mycanvas"></div>
                </div>
                <button type="button" onclick="runit()">Run</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>

        <section class="method first-of-group" id="intro">
          <div class="method-area method-area-expanded">
            <div class="method-copy">
              <h1 class="lesson-name">python title</h1>

            <div class="method-example">
              <div id="side-view">
                <div id="side-left">
                  <textarea id="authcode" cols="40" rows="10">
# This code will print out Hello World
print("Hello World")
                      </textarea
                  >
                  <script type="text/javascript">
                    // insert codemirror
                    var myCodeMirror = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(authcode, {
                      lineNumbers: true,
                      mode: "python"
                    });
                  </script>
                </div>
                <br />

                <div id="side-right">
                  <div id="console">
                    <pre id="output"></pre>
                  </div>
                  <!-- If you want turtle graphics include a canvas -->
                  <div id="mycanvas"></div>
                </div>
                <button type="button" onclick="runit()">Run</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
      </div>
```

Here is the onClick function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      // output functions are configurable.  This one just appends some text
      // to a pre element.
      function outf(text) {
        var mypre = document.getElementById("output");
        mypre.innerHTML = mypre.innerHTML + text;
      }
      function builtinRead(x) {
        if (
          Sk.builtinFiles === undefined ||
          Sk.builtinFiles["files"][x] === undefined
        )
          throw "File not found: '" + x + "'";
        return Sk.builtinFiles["files"][x];
      }

      // Here's everything you need to run a python program in skulpt
      // grab the code from your textarea
      // get a reference to your pre element for output
      // configure the output function
      // call Sk.importMainWithBody()
      function runit() {
        var prog = myCodeMirror.getValue();
        var mypre = document.getElementById("output");
        mypre.innerHTML = "";
        Sk.pre = "output";
        Sk.configure({ output: outf, read: builtinRead });
        (Sk.TurtleGraphics || (Sk.TurtleGraphics = {})).target = "mycanvas";
        var myPromise = Sk.misceval.asyncToPromise(function() {
          return Sk.importMainWithBody("<stdin>", false, prog, true);
        });
        myPromise.then(
          function(mod) {
            console.log("success");
                      ]
          },
          function(err) {
            console.log(err.toString());
          }
        );
      }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're reusing the same variable name `myCodeMirror`. Since the scripts on the page are executed in DOM order, the last value is used.

Additionally, you're using the same `runit()` method without differentiating which mirror to run, so it will always run on the last CodeMirror you setup.

---

First, you need to store the CodeMirrors in different variables:

```
var myCodeMirror1 = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(yourcode, {
    lineNumbers: true,
    mode: "python"
});

[...]

var myCodeMirror2 = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(authcode, {
    lineNumbers: true,
    mode: "python"
});
```

Then each button needs to tell `runit` which one to use:

```
<button type="button" onclick="runit(myCodeMirror1)">Run</button>

[...]

function runit(mirrorToRun) {
    var prog = mirrorToRun.getValue();
    [...]
}
```

Comment: That works perfect! Is there a way to update the output as well? Currently the submitted output goes into the top codemirror component only and updates just there.

Comment: @StackUnderFlow It's the same issue, you're reusing identifiers that need to be unique - both output areas has `id="output"`. So when `outf` does `document.getElementById("output")` it will always find the first output area. To fix this, you need to give them unique `id` values and (probably) pass a second argument to `outf` to tell it what id to use